# Setting up sharepoint for visibility of cell edits

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

I have a large excel sheet in sharepoint that is worked on by people from multiple physical locations, who can make edits to specific cells. However we regularly need to know, the values in which strings have been changed on or after a given date (as they may require follow-up). Back when we worked with non-sharepoint excel, it was an easy problem to fix by having a button that would change the value in "status" column to signify that some work was done and simultaneously append a cell in log column with the date of edit and user's initials.

But... that was in the good old days when VBA was a thing. Does anyone know of a way to do something like this in Sharepoint?

I know that in theory it's possible to check version history and compare a past version against the current one, but I was wondering if anyone knows of a way that would be somewhat practical for a common operation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

VBA is still a thing. Just because a file is stored in a SharePoint library does not mean you cannot use VBA.

BTW, there is no such thing as "sharepoint excel". Office 365 contains Excel online, which runs in the browser, and Excel files stored in SharePoint can be opened with Excel online. Excel online does not run VBA, though.

But Excel Online is not your only option for working with files stored in SharePoint. With Office 365 and Excel files stored in SharePoint you can still open these Excel files with Excel for desktop, which then can run the VBA just fine.

Also, with Office 365 and files stored in SharePoint, co-authoring allows multiple people to edit an Excel workbook simultaneously, from different devices and end points. Any user who opens the Excel workbook on a desktop client will be able to run the VBA commands in the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in another answer, VBA still works if the file is open in desktop version of Excel, however I agree that's not an optimal solution (additional step, .xlsm files can't be auto-saved...)

Instead of Excel, I'd use a sharepoint list for data entry, there you can enable [versioning](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-the-version-history-of-an-item-or-file-in-a-list-or-library-53262060-5092-424d-a50b-c798b0ec32b1) and also create an Excel file to analyse information.